# What methods inherited from the Object class should usually be overridden?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, overriding

I know that equals(), hashCode(), and toString() are three methods most classes should have overridden for that class and it's specific usage, but are there others I should be adding to my classes, and if so why would I use them and how do they work?

Comment: see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) of `Object` - there are only 4 methods that are neither `final` nor `@deprecated`¹: the only one from these not listed in the question is `clone()`, to create a copy of `this` (I prefer to create a copy-constructor, if needed) || **¹** `finalize()` was intended to be used as a de-constructor/clean-up, but: "*The use of finalization can lead to problems with security, performance, and reliability. See [JEP 421](https://openjdk.org/jeps/421) for discussion and alternatives.*"

Comment: Also what really should be overridden depends heavily on the use case. You don't *need* to override `toString` for every class you write for example.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What methods inherited from the `Object` class should *usually* be overridden?

None of them!  Some of them *can* be overridden, and often are.  But none of them *should* be overridden as a matter of course.

The following are the methods that can be overridden:

- `toString()` *can* be overridden if you want the result to represent aspects of the state of the target instance.
- `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` *can* be overridden<sup>1</sup> if you want the `equals` semantics to be based on instance's values rather than reference identity.
- `clone()` *can* be overridden to make `clone` a public method, or if the semantics of the default clone implementation are not what you need.
- `finalize()` *can* be overridden if you want the class to be finalizable<sup>2</sup>.
  The remaining `Object` methods are `final` so that they cannot be overridden.

---

<sup>1 - If you override one of these two methods you will most likely need to override the other to maintain the general `hashCode` contract.  Refer to the `hashCode()` [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) for details.

2 - You probably should not do this.  Finalization is deprecated and will be removed in a future Java version.  There better ways to do the cleanup that finalization was typically used for.  See [JEP 421](https://openjdk.org/jeps/421) for details.</sup>